# How to set ActionMailer SMTP settings in a YML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, actionmailer

For my deployment, I prefer to have all Rails configuration options in YML files under `config/`. I am having particular problems with `action_mailer.smtp_settings`.

I have a file, `config/smtp.yml` :

```
development:
  address: localhost
  port: 1025

test:

production:
  address: smtp.xs4all.nl
  port: 465
  authentication: plain
  user_name: xxxxx
  password: xxxxx
  tls: true
```

I then try to include these values via an initializer. `config/initializers/smtp.rb`:

```
options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'smtp.yml'))[Rails.env]

options.each do |name, value|
  Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[name.to_sym] = value
end unless options.nil?
```

This loads the `smtp.yml` file, parses that and returns the hash for the current environment, e.g.

```
 {"address"=>"smtp.xs4all.nl", "port"=>465, "authentication"=>"plain", "user_name"=>"xxxxx", "password"=>"xxxxx", "tls"=>true}
```

Converts the keys to symbols and adds that to the smtp-settings, resuling in e.g:

```
  irb(main):002:0> Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings
  => {:port=>465, :address=>"smtp.xs4all.nl", :authentication=>"plain", :user_name=>"xxxxx", :password=>"xxxx", :tls=>true}
```

But when deploying to production, this causes some conflict, probably because some part has not been booted yet. Capistrano fails with:

```
   * executing "cd -- /var/www/ANT_cms/releases/20131218170336 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
servers: ["li153-5.members.linode.com"]
[li153-5.members.linode.com] executing command
 ** [out :: li153-5.members.linode.com] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: li153-5.members.linode.com] undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Why is my `Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` nil here? How can I make sure that actionMailers config options are already loaded?

Comment: I don't think "tls" is a valid field for smtp_settings, that could be the reason why `Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[:tls]` returns nil. Take a look at  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: Yes, I don't see it in the documentation, but for me it solved the issue where I got certificate-errors. Setting this, fixed my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging deeper, I found the issue is that `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"` loads only a small subset, and not e.g. `ActionMailer`.

Adding an early exit to my loader fixes this in `config/initializers/smtp.rb`:

```
unless Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.nil?

  options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'smtp.yml'))[Rails.env]

  options.each do |name, value|
    Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[name.to_sym] = value
  end unless options.nil?

end
```

Then, the next issue is that action_mailer in production is set, but that smtp_settings does not have to be defined and filled with defaults, yet. So prefilling this with an empty hash solves the entire issue:

```
unless Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.nil?

  Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {}

  options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'smtp.yml'))[Rails.env]

  options.each do |name, value|
    Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[name.to_sym] = value
  end unless options.nil?
end
```

Still, somewhat ugly, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`config_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-config_for) for this:

```
Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = config_for(:smtp)
```

Comment: I hardly recommend adding .symbolize_keys method  Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = config_for(:smtp).symbolize_keys

Answer (score 0):

```
Portfolio::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = config_for(:smtp).symbolize_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure it more like Action Storage, by service, you can do something like this.

`config/mailer.yml`

```yaml
sendgrid: 
  user_name: apikey
  password: "<%= ENV.fetch("SENDGRIP_API_KEY") %>"
  address: smtp.sendgrid.net
  port: 587
  authentication: :plain
  enable_starttls_auto: true

gmail:
  user_name: xxxxx
  password: "<%= ENV.fetch("GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD") %>"
  address: smtp.gmail.com
  port: 587
  authentication: :plain
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  open_timeout: 5
  read_timeout: 5
```

`app/lib/mail/gmail_smtp.rb`

```rb
class GmailSmtp < Mail::SMTP; end
```

`config/initializers/mailer.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config_file = Rails.root.join("config/mailer.yml")
  action_mailer_config = ActiveSupport::ConfigurationFile.parse(config_file).deep_symbolize_keys

  # Default for all mailers
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = action_mailer_config[:sendgrid]
  
  config.action_mailer.gmail_smtp_settings = action_mailer_config[:gmail]
end
```

`app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default delivery_method: :gmail_smtp

  def my_notification
  end
end
```